# What does it mean "No Launcher activity found! and The launch will only sync the application package on the device!"

Tags: java, android

I got this warning from console when running my application on emulator
    No Launcher activity found!
    The launch will only sync the application package on the device!

In fact i have declared two activities as the GMapsActivity and MainActivity launcher in AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.emsgpstracking.fh"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >


        <activity

            android:name="com.emsgpstracking.fh.GMapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.main" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
             android:exported="false"
            android:name="com.emsgpstracking.fh.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.main.MAINACTIVITY" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
         <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />


    </application>




</manifest>
```

What's the reason? Please give me a solution

Answer (score 2):

The line:

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.main" />
```

Should be:

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
```